# Running into Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, create-table

While working on an assignment, I have been running into a few issues lately. While trying to place the following into the database, I keep running into syntax errors.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTID INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT
FNAME CHAR(10)
LNAME CHAR(10)
ADDRESS CHAR(10)
TELNUM INT(10)
SALESPERSONID INT(3)
 );

CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON (
SALESID INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT
FNAME CHAR(10)
LNAME CHAR(10)
OFFICENUM CHAR(4)
TELNUM CHAR(10)
);
```

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but it's been troublesome trying to figure it out. (Well for the past 3 days I was not able to work on this due to weather and the power being out)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah cause you are missing `,` after every column defintion. Your `CREATE TABLE` should be

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTID INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT,
FNAME CHAR(10),
LNAME CHAR(10),
ADDRESS CHAR(10),
TELNUM INT(10),
SALESPERSONID INT(3)
 );
```

Also, checking MySQL documentation for syntax help is way better idea than posting a question

Comment: I cannot believe that I missed something that was very simple. Thank you and I will make sure that I won't overlook something that small.